# validate Date Ajax and KeyUp in Calendar JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Im a newbie on JSF

I want to validate the date the user is adding on the "Calendar",

using the event "KeyUp" and ajax, but, it doesn't work.
anyone can help me?

Thanks .

```
<p:calendar id="fechaNacimiento" value="#{funcionarioController.funcionario.persona.fechaNac}"
                               pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" yearRange="c-60:c" navigator="true" locale="es" showOn="button" 
                               size="30" maxlength="10" maxdate="#{personaController.fecha}"
                               required="true" requiredMessage="Ingrese su Fecha de Nacimiento">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="#{personaController.timeZone}"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="de.common.DateValidator" />
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{funcionarioController.dateChange}" update=":acpCv:messages"/>  
       <p:ajax event="keyup" update="" listener="#{funcionarioController.validateDate}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

and my controller JAVA :

```
public void validateDate(){
        System.out.println("Validation Date");
    }
```

Comment: You can't hava a jsf-1.2 and 2/2.2 tag at the same time. And you already have a date validator… what does that do and why additional validation in the controller? And desvribe 'does not work' from a developer point of view

Comment: sorry the version I use is the 2  , sorry.

Comment: sorry , but part of that validation, I want the function "validateDate" run when the user types will not print date ... and not shows the message within the function

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. The term "validate" is misplaced and too ambiguous. What exactly are you trying to validate and why exactly are you doing it in an action method instead of a validator? Are you absolutely sure that you mean "validate" and not "convert"? The calendar component will namely only convert from string to date object and validators run only after converter. It can impossibly already give you a whole date object for validation after entering only 1 character. What problem exactly are you actually trying to solve in this XY-problem?